Riemannian Manifolds (Lee) Exercise 6-28 (d): Isometries converging pointwise converge topologically
Suppose $M$ is a connected, complete Riemannian manifold, $\mathrm{Iso}(M)$ is a smooth Lie group composed of all isometries of $M$, and $\phi_n$ is a sequence of isometries converging to an isometry $\phi$ pointwise. We have to show that $\phi_n\to \phi$ in the topology on $\mathrm{Iso}(M)$. The sketch provided is to construct $n+1$ generically positioned, close together points $p_0,\dots,p_{n+1}$, define $F:\mathrm{Iso}(M)\to M^{n+1}$ by $F(\phi)=(\phi(p_0),\dots, \phi(p_n))$, prove $F$ is continuous and injective (I can do this), then prove $F$ is closed (this is where I'm stuck). It follows that $F$ is homeomorphic to its image, and in particular pointwise convergence implies convergence in the Lie group $\mathrm{Iso}(M)$.
As far as I am aware, Lee never defines a topology on $\mathrm{Iso}(M)$, so the only information available about the topology is that $\mathrm{Iso}(M)$ is a Lie group acting smoothly on $M$. This information does not seem to be sufficient to determine the topology of $\mathrm{Iso}(M)$ though, because the discrete topology satisfies these constraints. Is there some reasonable requirement or assumption that can be made about the topology of $\mathrm{Iso}(M)$ so that we can show $F$ is closed?
I know that $\mathrm{Iso}(M)$ is typically equipped with the compact-open topology, but I'm trying to avoid using this since Lee never mentions it. I apologize that my question is not very precise.
EDIT: To respond to Moishe Kohan, I will outline the reasons why I do not think Lee is using the compact-open definition. (1) I found no mention of the compact-open topology in his introductions to topological, smooth, or riemannian manifolds. (2) If it is enough to prove uniform convergence on compact sets, there is a simple direct proof that pointwise convergence of isometries implies this. It involves choosing an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of each point, taking a finite subcover, and then picking $i$ large enough so that a point in each set of the cover is within $\epsilon$ of its limit. (3) If we do use the compact-open topology, I can't figure out how to work this into the argument sketched by Lee to show that $F$ is closed.

The usual topology on the isometry group is the compact-open topology or, equivalently, topology of uniform convergence on compacts. This is what Lee is using.

@MoisheKohan I responded to your comment in the post.

For locally compact metric spaces, topology of uniform convergence on compacts is equivalent to compact-open topology.

The assumption at the beginning of that problem is that the isometry group is a Lie group $G$ acting smoothly on $M$. So the topology in questino is the manifold topology on $G$.

@JackLee If we don't know the specific topology of this Lie group, can we really prove that F is a closed map?

If $F(\phi_k)\to \psi$ then $\phi_k\to \phi$ for some isometry $\phi$ with $F(\phi)=\psi$, so the image $S:=F(\mathrm{Iso}(M))\subseteq M^{n+1}$ is closed. The image $S$ is an orbit of the $\mathrm{Iso}(M)$-action on $M^{n+1}.$ As a closed orbit, $S\hookrightarrow M^{n+1}$ is an embedded submanifold. Therefore $F:\mathrm{Iso}(M)\to S$ is a smooth, $\mathrm{Iso}(M)$-equivariant bijection. Therefore it has constant rank, so it's a diffeomorphism, so $F:\mathrm{Iso}(M)\to M^{n+1}$ is a topological embedding.
